# How can i display a environment indicator notice on my dev and staging when browsing the site?

Tags: staging

I know there is a environment_indicator module that displays a bar on the bottom of the website showing if your on staging or dev. http://drupal.org/project/environment_indicator

I want to know if there is a way to do this without having to install a module, by doing it via the settings.php file where I can make it output some html to indicate im on staging or dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't output HTML (or text) directly from `settings.php` without throwing an error, since `settings.php` is interpreted during bootstrap.

Provided you have a clean install, on your staging site, have the following line in `settings.php`:

```
$conf['site_name'] = 'This is a staging site';
```

All assignments to the `$conf` array you do in `settings.php` will override whatever value you set the in the administrative GUI for the site.

An alternative solution, if you don't have a clean install and the site's name is no longer displayed by default, is to add your *own* conf variable to `settings.php`:

```
$conf['is_staging_p'] = TRUE;
```

and modify your theme to output some indicator if this predicate is TRUE;

Comment: yes that works, but i still have to configure either the blocks or edit the theme to print out the site_name variable. I was wondering if there was a way to just do it via the settings.php file and not have to touch anything else on the site.

Comment: I need to do this for a live site im cloning into staging servers.

Comment: i know im being a bit strict and limited what not the change. i dont even know if its possible. im just limiting it to just being able to edit the settings.php file and nothing else. I mean i can do a print_r on that page, but that throws an error since it will output before the headers... i wonder if its possible inject something after the headers, but it has to reside in settings.php

Comment: @duckx no, you can't do that without writing code further up the chain (ie in a module or theme). settings.php isn't the right place for display logic anyway...it's for settings :)